# How to lookup values in a loop and reduce run time?

Tags: r, performance, lookup-tables

I just want to say first that I'm pretty new to R coding. I wrote up some R code which will run over thousands of iterations.  The code works and gets the results that I need, however it takes way too long to run.  I'll first explain what the code is doing and then the code it self.  How can I make this more efficient and make it run in a relatively short time over 200K+ iterations?

There is a while loop which runs until the total dollars reach the target dollars.  First I generate a random number, which I look up on the Prob column in the  first table below which returns the Dist column (this value is stored as a string). I parse the string and get a value based on the distribution and add it to a vector. Then I use this value to do a another look up on the second table below and get a factor and save these factors for each value in a second vector. I do this loop until I reach my target dollars. Then I multiple the two vectors to get my result vector. This while loop is then looped 200K+ times.

```
Prob    Range       Dist
.12        5000     rgamma(1, 3, , 900) + 1000
.70      100000     rgamma(1, 1, , 900) + 5000
.85      350000     rgamma(1,0.9, , 150000) + 200000
.95     1500000     rgamma(1,0.8, , 230000) + 200000
1.0     2500000     runif(1, 1500000, 2500000)



  Range   Factor
   5000   rweibull(1, 20, 1.1)
 100000   rweibull(1, 30, 1.2)
 250000   rweibull(1, 25, 1.5)
2500000   rweibull(1, 25, 1.8)
```

Sample code is below.  I've used dummy values in many places, there is other operations having a couple more similar operations as below.  Ruing this 100 times takes about a minute.  When I run it thousands of time, it will take too long.  How can I make this code more efficient?

```
t <- proc.time()
#inputs
sims <- 100
totalD <- 0
totalRev <- c(150000000)
i <- 0
set.seed(1)

ProbRnge <- matrix(c(0.12, 0.70, 0.85, 0.95, 1, 
                     5000, 100000, 350000, 1500000, 2500000,
                     1000, 5000, 100000, 350000, 1500000), ncol=3)
Dis1 <- c("rgamma(1, 3.0268, , 931.44) + 1000", "rgamma(1, 1.0664, , 931.44) + 5000", 
         "rgamma(1, 1.0664, , 931.44) + 5000", "rgamma(1, 1.0664, , 931.44) + 5000", 
         "runif(1, 1250000, 2000000)")

SizeRnge <- c(5000, 100000, 250000, 2500000)
Dis2 <- c("rweibull(1, 20, 1.1)", "rweibull(1, 30, 1.2)", "rweibull(1, 25, 1.5)", 
         "rweibull(1, 25, 1.8)")

#simulation loop
for (j in 1:sims) {

  TotalDTemp <- NULL
  FacTmp <- NULL
  TotalDTemp <- vector()
  FacTmp <- vector()

  # loop while total simulated reached target total.
  while(totalD < totalRev[1])
  {
    i = i + 1
    #find where random number falls in range and look up distribution and calculate value and store in vector
    row_i <- which.max(ProbRnge[,1] > runif(1))
    tmpSize <- max(min(eval(parse(text=Dis1[row_i])), ProbRnge[row_i, 2]), ProbRnge[row_i, 3])

    if (totalD + tmpSize > totalRev[1]) {
      tmpSize = totalRev[1] - totalD
      totalD = totalD + tmpSize
    } else {
      totalD = totalD + tmpSize }

    TotalDTemp [i] <-tmpSize

    # take value an lookup up factor to apply and store in vector
    row_i <- which.max(SizeRnge > tmpSize)
    tempRTR <- max(min(eval(parse(text=Dis2[row_i])), 2), 1)
    FacTmp [i] <- tempRTR
  }

  DfacTotal <- TotalDTemp * FacTmp

  totalD = 0
  i = 0
}

proc.time() - t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you profile your code, you see that what is taking the most of time is parsing the expressions. You could do that beforehand (before the loops) by computing

```
expr1 <- lapply(Dis1, function(text) parse(text = text))
expr2 <- lapply(Dis2, function(text) parse(text = text))
```

And then using `eval(expr1[[row_i]])` instead of `eval(parse(text=Dis1[row_i]))`.

For me, this reduces computation time from 45 sec to less than 2 sec.

Comment: Thank you!!!! You are a genius!!.  I just tried your suggestion and it work very well. That is a huge reduction in time.
I tried to vote up the answer but I have less then 15 reputation.